# Getting a limit response from Loopback, when no authentication is provided

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I can't find a way to do it in the docs, and I have looked into as well here on Stack Overflow. I want to show a user a limited view of my JSON response from the API, before they have logged in.

So, as an example, I have a e-book I want to sell online. I want them only to see a preview link (epubFile.notAuthoried) of the book when not logged in, and the full link (epubFile.authorized) of the book when logged in. Both links are represented in the same table.

```
[
  {
    "title": "string",
    "subTitle": "string",
    "isPublished": true,
    "publicationDate": "2017-10-20T11:07:31.258Z",
    "epubFile": {
      "notAuthorized": "filename-noauth.epub"
      "authorized": "filename-auth.epub"
    }
    "id": "string",
    "createdOn": "2017-10-20T11:07:31.258Z",
    "updatedOn": "2017-10-20T11:07:31.258Z"
  }
]
```

Is it even possible to filter out fields from the API Endpoints in loopback? 
Or do I need to build a new custom API Endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you'll have to set the permissions on your `find` and `findById` methods to $everyone so that both authorized and unauthorized users can call them

```
{     
  "name": "eBook",
   "base": "PersistedModel",
   [...]
   "acls": [
     "accessType": "READ",
     "principalType": "ROLE",
     "principalId": "$everyone",
     "permission": "ALLOW",
     "property":["find", "findById]
    ]
}
```

Next, you'll have to hook into the remote methods and modify the response depending on if hte user is logged in or not

```js
const previewProperites = ['title', 'subTitle', etc...]
Ebook.afterRemote('find', (ctx, ebooks, next) => {
  // pseudo code
  if(!ctx.options.accessToken){
    // no user logged in, only keep preview properties
    ebooks.forEach(book => {
      // get the properties of the book
      var eBookProperties = Object.keys(book.__data);

      eBookProperties.forEach(bookProp =>{
        if(!previewProperties.some(pProp => pProp === bookProp)){
          // ebook property not in preview list, so remove it
          delete book.__data[bookProp]; // .__data is where loopback keeps its actual data
        }
      });
    });
  }
  next();
}
```

Comment: Just because I'm still a little newbie in Loopback, the hook is placed in the ebook.js under common/models, correct?

I will try the suggested solution tomorrow, thanks @YeeHaw1234 for the answer and thanks for the grammar corrections on the text halfer :)

Comment: You can put the code in your ebook.js file, but we've found that it's easier to keep the code clean if you create a folder (/common/models/ebook/), and create a .js file for each bit of functionality (/ebook/hidePropertiesForPreview.js).  Then, in your ebook.js file, require this new .js file and call it